# Video editing: change frame rate so that animations etc. adapt to it and don't mess up

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, video, frame-rate

I edited my video while the frame rate was set to 24, but I want to render my video in higher frame rate (in 50, 48 or 60 frames). When I set the frame rate to 50, everything in the video gets twisted.
I use different animations for text, sound (.wav) and clips (.mkv and .avi), including opacity and fades. These get completely jumbled when I change the frame rate:

24 FPS:

[image]

60 FPS:

[image]

I found out that you can adjust something like this with the Time Stretching option, but nothing seems to change at all when I adjust it. Tried setting Old to 24 and New to 60, among others, and there was no difference. Is this only supported for 3D animation and not for video editing?

How can I change the frame rate so that the start positions and lenghts/speed of the channels, images, clips and its animation keyframes adjust to the frame rate so that the cuts are the same as with the old frame rate?

Thanks in advance!